# Ajax call aborted before redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an issue with which I am stuck :

I have an html file which has few hyperlinks on it, on clicking on any of those hyperlinks 
, a dynamic url is generated and user is redirected to that dynamically created URL.

Now I am trying to make an ajax call on click of those hyperlinks before it is redirected, but 
it fails, and firebug show aborted ajax request.

Am i not doing in correct way ? why is it getting aborted ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide some code

Answer (score 3):

As I see you are already told moving to a new location aborts everything. I want to add that you need to keep in mind that if you do something like:

```
//hyperlinkclick function
{

   $.ajax({ 
      ... });

   window.location = 'somewhere under the rainbow ... '; 
}
```

This doesnt mean your ajax call has been executed before the relocation! Ajax call is async, so if you want to relocate after the call is complete you can either set the relocating line in the success callback of the ajax call or you can use it as promise:

```
var call = $.ajax({ ... });
call.done(function() { 
   window.relocate = "the middle of nowhere";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you click a hyperlink that will trigger a url change, aborting everything. If you try to do something on the click of that hyperlink it will be aborted, due to the browser moving to a new location. To successfully run an ajax before actually moving to the url, you would have to do something like this:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/myDynamicUrl"></a>

document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  doMyAjaxThing(function () {
    location.href = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //hyperlinkclick function
    {

       $.ajax({ 
  success: function addgetdata(returns) {
       window.location = 'somewhere under the rainbow ... '; 
}
          ... });


    }
```

You need to use the ajax method in your hyperlinkclick function, so when you click it, it will raise the ajax function first. and you put the redirection yin your ajax success function, so when the ajax is finished, it will redirect to the new url.

yours,
Ivan